# Cannot fetch any C# variable from ASPX for Asp:TextBox parameter

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, css

**How can I use C# methods to alter an Asp:TextBox item's Text value(or any other value) dynamically only from ASPX side?**

I can access any C# variable using <%= .... %> to select a class for a `div`. But cannot use it for any Aspx item's Text property.

Here, the three aspx items fail to fetch the variable from C# part but divs are easily using that for selecting a CSS class

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="test.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <link href="site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="testBox" runat="server" Text="<%= test.TestClass.TestMethod() %>"></asp:TextBox>
     bye bye world!
    </div>
        <div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%= test.TestClass.TestMethod() %>'></asp:TextBox>
     bye bye world!
    </div>


        <div class="<%=test.TestClass.CustomCSSClass() %>" >hello world! </div>
        <div class='<%=test.TestClass.CustomCSSClass() %>' >hello world! </div>
        <div class=<%=test.TestClass.CustomCSSClass() %> >hello world! </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Output is:

[image]

As you can see, only divs are accepting <%= ... %> and they are styled. But Asp:TextBox items having issues and printing the C# code directly instead of the value.

Here is the CSS(not related but putting anyway):

```
body {
}

.CustomCSSClass {
    margin-top:50px;width:300px;height:200px;background-color:red;
}
```

Here is the C# methods that Im testing:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace test
{
    public class TestClass
    {
        public static string TestMethod()
        {
            return "ASPX and HTML and CSS";
        }

        public static string CustomCSSClass()
        {
            return "CustomCSSClass";
        }
    }
}
```

While double-quote, single-quote and even quoteless versions work for selecting a style class, aspx fails to compile for quoteless version and other two are giving wrong results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<%= ... %>` bee stings are short hand for calling `Response.Write()`. In other words, their result goes directly to the output stream written to the browser. You can't assign it to the property of an ASP.Net control. ASP.Net controls are *server-side* controls, meaning they have properties that are processed by the server before html is generated and later written to the response stream. The two items work at different levels of abstraction, and don't really fit well together.

If you want to set the text property of a control, do it in a code-behind file, or in a server-side method in your same file. If you don't want to have a code-behind file or server-side methods, then you don't need server-controls and can just use an html input element instead.

Comment: So, if I needed a user-server communication, I need C# to change/compare input values? I need to make it from aspx side.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking, but I think that yes, you would.

Comment: To expand: data sent from the user to the server is processed through an http request. This could be handled in a [WebMethod] (ajax request), as a response to a server control's event, reading html form parameters directly in a POST, or by looking at the url parameters in a GET